# Using Spring @Transactional with a combination of readOnly and write, when does this entity get committed?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Given

```
class CallingClass {
  @Autowired SomeService someService;
  doit() {
    someService.readOnlyCall();
  }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class SomeService {
  @Autowired AnotherService anotherService;
  readOnlyCall() {
    // logic which may then do...
    anotherService.writeCall();
  }
}

class AnotherService {
  @Transactional // not readonly
  writeCall() {
    // save some entity
  }
}
```

Will the entity be committed to the database when the writeCall method exits or when the readOnlyCall method exits?

And how can you modify it so it commits after the writeCall method?

Answer (score 0):

The entity will not be committed to the database in both method exits. It is because

- Your SomeService class has read-only (which you have specify). It will set FlushMode.NEVER which to prevent commit the transaction
- Your SomeService class and AnotherService class has REQUIRED propagation type(which is by default and you have not specify other type for both class). It will create a new transaction if doesn't exist but will use current transaction if there is.
- In this case the SomeService class begin transaction with read-only and AnotherService class will participates in the existing read-only transaction. Therefore, no entity will be committed.

To make it commits after the writeCall method, just add setting on writeCall method as below:

```
@Transactional (readOnly = false, propagation =Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) // not readonly
writeCall() {
// save some entity
}
```

These settings have precedence for writeCall method. It will suspend current read-only transaction and create a new read/write transaction. Therefore, it will commits after the writeCall method complete transaction.